# Segmentation faults when modifying cv::Mat data in c++

Tags: c++, opencv

Please let me know if this question is too broad, but I am trying to learn some c++ so I thought it would be a good idea to try and recreate some opencv functions.

I am still grabbing the frames or reading the image with opencv's API, but I then want to feed the cv::Mat into my custom function(s), where I modify its data and return it to display it. (For example a function to blur the image, where I pass the original Mat to a padding function, then the output of that to a fn that convolves the padded image with the blurring kernel, and returns the Mat to cv for displaying)

I am a little confused as to what the best (or right) way to do this is. OpenCV functions use a function argument as the return matrix ( `cv_foo(cv::Mat src_frame, cv::Mat dst_frame)` ) but I am not entirely clear how this works, so I have tried a more familiar approach, something like

```
cv::Mat my_foo(cv::Mat src_frame) {
     // do processing on src_frame data
     return dst_frame;
}
```

where to access the data from src_frame I use `uchar* framePtr = frame.data;` and to create the dst_frame I followed [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/81831/convert-stdvectordouble-to-mat-and-show-the-image/) suggestion

```
cv::Mat dst_frame = cv::Mat(n_rows, n_cols, CV_8UC3);
memcpy(dst_frame.data, &new_data_array, sizeof(new_data_array));
```

I have however encountered various segmentation faults that I find hard to debug, as it seems they occur almost at random (could this be due to the way I am handling the memory management with frame.data or something like that?).

So to come back to my original question, what is the best way to access, modify and pass the data from a cv::Mat in the most consistent way?

I think what would make the most intuitive sense to me (coming from numpy) would be to extract the data array from the original Mat, use that throughout my processing and then repackage it into a Mat before displaying, which would also allow me to feed any custom array into the processing without having to turn it into a Mat, but I am not sure how to best do that (or if it is the right approach).

Thank you!

EDIT:
I will try to highlight the main bug in my code.

One of the functions I am trying to replicate is a conversion from bgr to greyscale, my code looks like this

```cpp
cv::Mat bgr_to_greyscale(cv::Mat& frame){

    int n_rows = frame.rows;
    int n_cols = frame.cols;
    uchar* framePtr = frame.data;
    int channels = frame.channels();

    uchar grey_array[n_rows*n_cols];

    for(int i=0; i<n_rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n_cols; j++){
            uchar pixel_b = framePtr[i*n_cols*channels + j*channels];
            uchar pixel_g = framePtr[i*n_cols*channels + j*channels + 1];
            uchar pixel_r = framePtr[i*n_cols*channels + j*channels + 2];

            uchar pixel_grey = 0.299*pixel_r + 0.587*pixel_g + 0.144*pixel_b;

            grey_array[i*n_cols + j] = pixel_grey;

        }
    }

    cv::Mat dst_frame = cv::Mat(n_rows, n_cols, CV_8UC1, &grey_array);

    return dst_frame;
}
```

however when I display the result of this function on a sample image I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E92QA.png) result: the bottom part of the image looks like random noise, how can I fix this? what exactly is going wrong in my code?

Thank you!

Comment: _"Could this be due to the way I am handling the memory management with frame.data?"_. We have no way of knowing.  A segmentation fault is a safe indicator that you have at least one bug in your code somewhere, involving access of memory that does not belong to your program.  A debugger will offer clues.

Comment: Use cv::Mat dst = src.clone(); which will allocate ne memory on the heap for the pixel data. when you return the cv::Mat that return value will be linked to the same memory on the heap. When there is no cv::Mat linked to that memory anymore, the memory on the heap will be given free.

Answer (score 2):

This question is too broad to answer in any detail, but generally a `cv::Mat` is a wrapper around the image data akin to the way an `std::vector<int>` is a wrapper around a dynamically allocated array of `int` values or an `std::string` is a wrapper around a dynamically allocated array of characters with one exception: a `cv::Mat` will not perform a deep copy of the image data on assignment or usage of the copy constructor.

```
std::vector<int> b = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int> a = b;
// a now contains a copy of b and a[0] = 42 will not effect b.

cv::Mat b = cv::imread( ... );
cv::Mat a = b;
// a and b now wrap the same data.
```

But that said, you should not be using `memcpy` et. al. to copy a `cv::Mat` ... You can make copies with `clone` or `copyTo`. [From the cv documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html):

```
Mat F = A.clone();
Mat G;
A.copyTo(G);
```